# laravel 4.2 route with trailing '/'

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, routes

we have a REST Api, that declares the following routes for entity:

```
 Route::get('entities', 'Api2EntityController@index');
 Route::get('entities/{entityId}', 'Api2EntityController@show');
 Route::post('entities', 'Api2EntityController@store');
 Route::put('entities/{entityId}', 'Api2EntityController@update');
 Route::delete('entities/{entityId}', 'Api2EntityController@destroy');
```

POSTing data to entities would correctly call Api2EntityController@store.
But the same request to entities/ (has trailing '/') would call Api2EntityController@index.

we have tried adding a new route for POST or using regex or changing the order of the routes, still we have no solution so far on how to accept the POST on the URL with trailing '/'

Answer (score 0):

There is a rewrite active to remove any trailing slashes.

Check your public/.htaccess file

```
   # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
   RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]
```